# IPERF; Packet loss over adjacent wifi channels

Tags: wifi, iperf

I have two iperf clients and servers. Both on 5GHz. Both are on 20MHz channel. One iperf client is sending data over channel 36 and the other one is sending data over channel 40. While sending data on both channels simultaneously there is a huge loss while there is almost no loss when we send data through either of the iperf clients.
What are the possible reasons for this scenario? And how to correct them?

Note: There are no other wifi devices working on these channels. 
Experiment is set up in a room so range wont be an issue.
UDP is being used.

iperf server command:
`iperf -s -u -w 320k`

iperf client command: `iperf -c 192.168.XX.XXX -u -w 320k -t 10 -i 1 -b 300M`

Answer (score 1):

There will be packet drops if rts/cts is on.
1st access point will keep on sending data while 2nd access point waits for the 1st to send all data. 2nd will drop packets as it is waiting to send data. Although the channels are different but access points will detect channel interference.

You should consider having channel 36 and 44 to solve the problem.

There may be other reasons for these.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, CH36 (5180 MHz) shouldn't interfere with CH40 (5200 MHz) if you are using 20MHz channel in both APs. So interference shouldn't be a reason for your iPerf results.

Also, the RTS/CTS option can usually be turned off by most APs (through Web admin page). It shouldn't affect iPerf results as well because RTS/CTS is normally used to prevent collisions for small frames - whereas iPerf normally sends large frames.

It's not entirely clear about the network topology you are testing. Are the two APs completely independent or connected? Where are the iPerf servers - are they connected over WiFi as well or via Eth?

Finally I doubt the "-w" option you are using. You are testing UDP, but "-w" is for specifying TCP windows size.

Comment: We're using 4 PCS and 2 AP's (Access Points) in the same room. PC A is connected via Ethernet to AP-A while PC B is connected via Ethernet to AP-B PC C is connected to AP-A via wifi while PC D is connected to AP-B via wifi. AP-A is working on channel 36 while AP-B is working on channel 40.

We're simultaneously sending data from PC A to PC C and from PC B to PC D.

Comment: Now theoretically interference shouldn't be a reason for the iperf results but we are getting this problem again and again. To test this we put the AP's close together. And we got nearly 100 percent loss in one communication while 0 percent loss in the other communication showing that one AP was getting captured.

Comment: What we feel the problem is as they are 20MHz channels so they do end up meeting at the boundary hence the carrier sense is being enable because of that.

Comment: So which connection suffers 100% losses?

C --> AP_A --> A (AP_A on CH36)
or,
D --> AP_B --> D (AP_B on CH40)

If you change AP_B from CH40 to CH48 or CH161 (if possible / depends on your AP) - would you still observe that behaviour?

What if you swap client/server side, say now A sends to C; and D sends to B instead?

The your reported results are indeed very strange with 20 MHz channel.